# Transaction rollback to a savepoint fails in MyBatis

Tags: transactions, mybatis, rollback

I have problem rolling back to a particular savepoint using Mybatis SqlSession instance. I do not have Spring framework in my web application. Hence I am manually rolling back the transactions whenever the second insertion fails.

```
    private SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory;

    private MyRepositoryDAO()
    {
       sqlSessionFactory = MyBatisConnectionFactory.getSqlSessionFactory();
    }

    SqlSession session = sqlSessionFactory.openSession();
    Savepoint savePointA = session.getConnection.setSavePoint();

    if(insertionSuceeded)
    {
       session.commit();
    }
    else
    {
        session.rollback();
    }

    If(anotherInsertionSucceeded)
    {
         session.commit();
    }
    else
    {
          session.getConnection().rollback(savePointA)
     }
```

If i run this piece of code i am getting this below error. 
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: SAVEPOINT 688bd22f_1442b1b7a9c__8000 does not exist

Not sure what I am missing here. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL all transaction's savepoints are deleted when commit or rollback without savepoint is performed.

So if `anotherInsertionSucceeded==false` transaction is first committed or rolled back and all savepoints are deleted and then rollback to savepoint fails.